# How to pass a function reference as a parameter that needs to be called inside the caller function in Java

Tags: java

Consider following scenario where from main method, based on some condition I am calling method func. In func, I need to call diff. method based on whatever I am passing as parameter in func. How do we do that?

```
void mainMethod(){
    if(...)
        func(methodX);  
    else
        func(methodY);  

}

void func(... x) <- takes method name as parameter
{
    // do something
    // call method received in importing parameter x
}

void methodX()
{
    // do something
}

void methodY()
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no "pure" function pointers in Java.

**Up to Java 7 you have to use interfaces**:

```
void mainMethod() {
    if(...)
        func(new MethodX());
    else
        func(new MethodY());
}

void func(Runnable x) {
    x.run();
}

private class MethodX implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
}

private class MethodY implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

**in Java 8 you can use method references**:

```
void mainMethod(){
    if(...)
        func(this::methodX); // or the second line
        //func(() -> methodX());
    else
        func(this::methodY); // or the second line
        //func(() -> methodY());
    }

void func(Runnable x) {
    x.run();
}

public void methodX() {
    // do something
}

public void methodY() {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling this method every time, right?

```
void func(... x)
{
    // do something
    // call method received in importing parameter x
}
```

If i understand you right you can do the following:

```
void mainMethod()
{
    // do something here and called directly method
    if(...)
        methodX()
    else
        methodY()
}
```